# Knowing user is sshing in from a shell script?

Tags: macos, ssh

I have a shell script which I would like to do one thing if the user is physically using the computer, and one thing if the user is logged in via SSH.

How would I go about doing that?

In more specific terms, my normal machine is OS X, and there I want to use a OS X graphical editor (BBEdit) as my EDITOR. However, if I'm SSHing into my Mac from my netbook, I want to use vim - I don't have a graphical connection to my Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the SSH_CONNECTION, SSH_TTY, or DISPLAY environment variables.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ssh.1.html

```
 SSH_CONNECTION        Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.  The variable contains
                       four space-separated values: client IP address, client port number, server IP
                       address, and server port number.
```

Edit: SSH_CLIENT is also an option, but it doesn't appear in the man page.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you very much for your link to the ssh man page!

Answer (score 1):

Compare your `env` locally and when logged in via SSH.

I have e.g. `SSH_CONNECTION`, `SSH_CLIENT`, `SSH_TTY` that are only defined when logged in via SSH.

Comment: You beat me to a few seconds ;)

Comment: @Karolos See, you still got the checkmark for the more thorough answer ;)

Comment: I'm new here, so I am not used to think that several people are also looking at it too while I reply ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe /var/run/utmpx (see "man utmpx") has this information. If you run "who", you see that the who command can tell if you are connected from a remote node (and even knows where you connected from).

So you could always use the who command and massage the output to determine this.

Note: I believe the answers above (about using SSH_CONNECTION) are a better solution.

Comment: The `utmpx` file (more commonly named `utmp`) already has a strictly defined format. It's better to read it directly than parse `who`, since the latter is not always consistent.

Comment: Gwawity: I disagree from a shell script. If doing this from Python or C, I would agree, but from a shell script I would argue against parsing this (binary) file directly. But others have suggested using the SSH_* environment variables, which is a better answer.

Comment: Notifying @grawity about a response.